# Using commas in a number type input

Tags: html, html-input

I have an `input` field of `type="number"`, I want to put an initial value in the field which may be a large number. I was specifically asked to display large numbers with commas to make them more readable so I'm using the `.toLocaleString()` function to get the number as a string with commas.

Chrome it seems doesn't allow commas in number fields. Is there any way around this? I don't want to use a text field if possible because I don't want the user to be able to input any letters under any circumstance and I would rather not have to do input validation if I can avoid it.

Is there any way to display a number with commas in a number field that is cross-browser friendly? Alternatively, is there a way to just display an arbitrary string in a number field?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number), the `placeholder` attribute can hold arbitrary strings, though that attribute needs to be used [carefully](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Labels).

```html
<input type="number" placeholder="1,000,000" step="10" 
 onClick="this.value = this.value || 1000000" />
```

Comment: this is sort of what I expected to be the closest thing to what I wanted. But unfortunately it grays out the placeholder text. Its not that I want a string to represent what to type in the box, I want there to already be a value in the box that the user can change or do nothing to

Comment: You cannot display a number with editable commas in an `input type="number"` element. The closest you can get is the placeholder. I've added an `onClick` attribute that will fill in the number automatically if the field is blank.